# How to add the test cases to a test-suite file that calls other test suites in TestNG?

Tags: testng

I have a testNG.xml file having the code as mentioned below.This file is calling 2 other test suite files- Suite1 and Suite2. But I want to add some test cases to this file as well. Can  I do this and if yes then how?

```
<parameter name="browser" value="firefox"></parameter>
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter" />
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter" />
</listeners>

<suite-files>
    <suite-file path="./Suite1.xml" />
    <suite-file path="./Suite2.xml" />
</suite-files>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the DTD of the file in order to understand what you are allowed to do: http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd.php

In your case, you can add test cases without problem:

```
<parameter name="browser" value="firefox"></parameter>
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter" />
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter" />
</listeners>

<suite-files>
    <suite-file path="./Suite1.xml" />
    <suite-file path="./Suite2.xml" />
</suite-files>

<test>
    <classes>
        <class>...</class>
        ...
    </classses>
    ...
<test>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the file path in suite-file Like added Suite 1 and suite 2 added.

```
<suite-files>
    <suite-file path="./Suite1.xml" />
    <suite-file path="./Suite2.xml" />
    <suite-file path="./Suite3.xml" />
</suite-files>
```

Comment: This isn't really answering the question - the OP wants to add specific *test cases* as well as the test suites. If the only way to do this is to wrap the test cases in a separate test suite, please say so.